# Односвязный список. Операция удаления элемента

Tags: алгоритм, односвязный-список

Есть ли способ удалить элемент из односвязного списка за О(1)? При условии, что у нас есть указатель на удаляемый элемент.

Comment: Как вариант — перекопировать следующий в удаляемый, и удалить следующий...

Comment: @Harry, и что делать, если он последний?

Comment: @avp Добавить еще один и удалять :)

Comment: @Lil_Chil, если адреса указателя на начало списка у вас нет, то первый и последний в списке удалить не получится. И сами, наверное, понимаете, что если на данные в списке есть указатели из других структур, то копировать элементы списка друг в друга нельзя

Comment: Есть интерфейс односвязного списка, который приписывают Джону Кармаку. В нем можно удалять и добавлять элемент за `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

В `C` и в `C++` можно сделать односвязный список с удалением элемента за константу. Для этого в интерфейс функций добавляется дополнительный уровень косвенности: функции получают не адрес узла, а адрес указателя на адрес узла (обычно в предыдущем элементе списка). Идею подал Джон Кармак.

```
// gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 carmack-list.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;
struct node_t {
    char value;
    node_t *next;
};

void insert_head(node_t **head, char value) {
    node_t *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}

void remove_head(node_t **head) {
    node_t *old_node = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(old_node);
}

node_t **find(node_t **head, char value) {
    node_t **node;
    for (node = head; *node != NULL; node = &(*node)->next) {
        if ((*node)->value == value) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

node_t *make_list(const char *s) {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    for (int i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        insert_head(&head, s[i]);
    }
    return head;
}

void print_list(node_t *head) {
    for (node_t *node = head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        putc(node->value, stdout);
    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
}

int main() {
    node_t *list = make_list("C+-C+-C+-C");
    print_list(list);
    for (; ; ) {
        node_t **node = find(&list, 'C');
        if (*node == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        remove_head(node);
        print_list(list);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 carmack-list.c && ./a.out 
> C+-C+-C+-C
> +-C+-C+-C
> +-+-C+-C
> +-+-+-C
> +-+-+-
> ```

Comment: Супер! Для лучшего (более быстрого) понимания читателями сути, я бы добавил несколько слов -- *"...добавляется дополнительный уровень косвенности: функции получают не адрес узла, а адрес указателя на адрес узла* ***в предыдущем элементе списка***" / Кстати, мне помнится подобная идея была у Кнута в т. 1

Comment: @avp, спасибо. Я добавил "обычно в предыдущем элементе списка". Для головы списка это указатель на локальную переменную указывающую на голову списка. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо, идея классная. Но можно Вас попросить на пальцах простыми словами описать как будет работать алгоритм удаления элемента за константу? С этим вашим доп. уровнем косвенности.(Код для меня сложный).

Comment: В функцию удаления передаётся адрес поля `next` предыдущего узла. Функция удаляет следующий узел и исправляет поле в предыдущем. Это в каком-то смысле обман - указатели указывают не на сами узлы, а на поля в предыдущих узлах. В языках без возможности указывать на поле делается указатель на предыдущий узел, а для головы списка заводится дополнительный "узел перед началом списка".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А если нет возможности передать адрес next предыдущего узла? Чтобы его передать, нужно перебрать весь список и найти его, а это уже будет O(n)

Comment: "В языках без возможности указывать на поле делается указатель на предыдущий узел, а для головы списка заводится дополнительный "узел перед началом списка"."